# How to find show_in_menu.xml Formatter file in ServiceNow?

Tags: servicenow

In Navigator, System UI -> UI Formatter(Search for: Name=Show In Menu) as below
https://instancename.service-now.com/sys_ui_formatter_list.do?sysparm_query=name%3DShow%20In%20Menu&sysparm_list_mode=grid

I am wondering where I can find this Formatter: show_in_menu.xml?

Answer (score 1):

So this is considered a black-box thing of SN.  This exists in the file system on the installation of your instance, but not in the code.  Same with the activity formatter.  Look it up.  It's the same.

Now if it weren't black-boxed you'd be able to find it on the sys_ui_macro table or the sys_ui_page table.  But alas, this one isn't there.

Answer (score 0):

Try with different query: `sysparm_query=formatterLIKEmenu`